# Visual Studio Online Containers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm trying to create a remote environment using Visual Studio Code. I would like to create a custom dockerfile for my container. I've been following the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/online/reference/configuring

I'm using a dockerFile reference (but I've tried the image reference as well). Everytime I get the same default container.

This is my .devcontainer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Python 3",
    "context": "..",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",

    // Use 'settings' to set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create. 
    // You can edit these settings after create using File > Preferences > Settings > Remote.
    "settings": { 
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
        "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
        "python.linting.enabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/bin/pylint"
    },

    // Use 'appPort' to create a container with published ports. If the port isn't working, be sure
    // your server accepts connections from all interfaces (0.0.0.0 or '*'), not just localhost.
    // "appPort": [ 9000 ],

    // Install flask and any other dependencies
    "postCreateCommand": "sudo pip install -r requirements.txt",

    // Comment out next line to run as root
    "remoteUser": "vscode",

    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created in the array below.
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "quicktype.quicktype"
    ]
}
```

The rest of the config seems to work - the extensions work, the requirements.txt is installed. But the dockerfile seems to be ignores or errors - but I do not know where I can see any error logs.

I've also tried pointing at this repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python but the same thing happens. That dockerfile points to python:3 which should give version 3.8.1 - but the version on the environment is 3.8.0 which is the default image.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - this feature hasn't been released yet. For once it seems the docs are ahead of the code.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsonline/issues/194